# Open firefox with installed plugins

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I am using

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

to open Firefox and scrape javascript data.

Is there a way to open firefox with installed plugins, because now it uses the "clean" installation without any plugins?

Comment: I have Create a profile and store in D:\selenium\firefox_profile and use this code to get it

java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "D:\selenium\firefox_profile"

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Create a profile and store in `D:\selenium\firefox_profile` and use this code to get it

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -firefoxProfileTemplate "D:\selenium\firefox_profile"
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. This is the link to create a Firefox profile:

[link](https://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/05/creating-firefox-profile-for-your-selenium-rc-tests/)

Then you have to use the following code:
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('D:/selenium/firefox_profile/')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(fp)